# Can't run eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I downloaded eclipse IDE and extracted it, but when I run it I get this error:

```
Error: could not open 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\amd64\jvm.cfg'
```

PS : I already have JDK and my windows is 64bit

Updating JDK to 1.7 didn't help (because I already have it) and other solutions that I couldn't understand (maybe because instead of amd64 in other posts it was "I'and 3 digits'").

Comment: ever tried to start with administrator privileges?

Comment: BTW I have the path set to : C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin

Comment: does your eclipse has permissions to open that file

Comment: I dont know I will try to check

Comment: how to give it a permission ?

Comment: rightclick the `.exe`, and select "Run as administrator"

Comment: **No**.  Don't run Java with administrator privileges.  That's just dangerous.  Peter Horvath's solution should pan out for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the problem of your Eclipse, but your JRE. Eclipse needs a JRE (Java Runtime Environment)  to run. I  suggest to remove your  currently installed version,  and download a new one  from  the Oracle.

Comment: It's looking for a file in the JVM though.  And yes, on my linux setup, that library exists in my JVM.

Comment: I downloaded it before , will u specify which one ? I downloaded java_ee_sdk-6u4-jdk7-windows-x64.exe

Comment: @Makoto You  have right, I'm  sorry! I  fixed my answer - and were very happy a  changed vote  direction. :-)

Comment: @MohamedAtef It is not important,  although  the best if you use  a 64bit java7. You need a working jdk and a working jre, too,  but your current jre is damaged. Uninstall the  old, damaged things  and reinstall a working version.

Comment: so I should download jre7 windows x86 (for windows 64 bit ) ?

Comment: Download a jdk 7 for 64-bit windows. JDK contains a jre,  too. Give eclipse.ini the  path of the jdk which you want to use.

Comment: I gave it the loaction to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin\javaw.exe

Comment: now it says "java was started but returned exit code=13" and a long list of code , I still cant run it :(

Comment: exit code 13 ==  Permission denied

Comment: Don't know, it needed a deeper examination of your computer.

Comment: It worked now , I had to change program files (x86) to program files